# download file from html page not working

Tags: java, html, servlets, jboss

I uploaded new app on **Jboss 7**.

That app, amoung other things, can create file, save it and hopfully download it with `html5` tag.
After generated, the file saves on absolute path that I get from 
`getServletContext().getRealPath("/");`

By the server log I can tell that those actions done perfectly.
The file is created and saved.
The problem is with the download part.

I am trying to download the file with html5 tag.
`<a href=path+file name> download>Get Numbers!</a>`

I am using exactly the same path that I used to save the file on the server and I keep getting that `fail-no file` error from Chrome.

Ideas?

Comment: What is the actual URL being produced for that link?  What is the server's response to the request?

Comment: The path for the saved file is "/opt/repo/versions/7.1/standalone/tmp/vfs/tempc56e386fb58c08a8/SlL.war-269016b5c31c942c/serial.xls, the Url for that Link is <a href="/opt/repo/versions/7.1/standalone/tmp/vfs/tempc56e386fb58c08a8/SlL.war-269016b5c31c942c/serial.xls" download>Get Numbers!</a>

Comment: And does your website *have* that path?  That looks more like a file system path...

Comment: It have it. if not, i will get "java.io.FileNotFoundException: (No such file or directory)" when saving the file

Comment: You wouldn't get a `FileNotFoundException` for a 404 error on a web server.  I think you're confusing website URLs with file system paths.  They are very different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am using exactly the same path that I used to save the file on the server

There's the problem.  Your file path is something like this:

```
/opt/repo/versions/7.1/standalone/tmp/vfs/tempc56e386fb58c08a8/SlL.war-269‌​016b5c31c942c/serial.xls
```

That's fine *on the server* when getting the file from the file system.  But that path means nothing to a web browser.  The web browser is making a request to the web server for a file *known to the web server*.

So, for example, if your web server root is here:

```
/opt/mywebserver
```

Then that path ends up requesting this:

```
/opt/webserver/opt/repo/versions/7.1/standalone/tmp/vfs/tempc56e386fb58c08a8/SlL.war-269‌​016b5c31c942c/serial.xls
```

That file doesn't exist, so the web server responds with a 404 error.

You need to convert the *file system* path to a *URL* in order to use it in the markup.  (And that path needs to be publicly visible to the web server, within its own path structure.)